# How to fix Nikon D5200 mode dial giving incorrect modes?

Tags: nikon, dslr, manual-mode, shooting-mode

I have a Nikon D5200 DSLR and I am facing problem with the mode dial. Here is what is happening:

1. Changing mode dial to Landscape, Child or Sport gets me to Manual mode.
2. Changing mode dial to Macro gets me to Effect mode.

Basically, when I change modes using the dial, the camera shows me the wrong modes on screen.

Comment: It sounds like it is broken. Was it always this way? When did it start? Have you contacted Nikon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your camera needs to be examined by a Nikon Service Center. Here is a link to a list of [locations in India](http://www.nikon.co.in/en_IN/servicecentres.page?).

It might be worth a try to check and see if there is a more current firmware version than the one running on your D5200. If so, try updating the firmware and see if that helps the problem. If you are running the current version of the firmware, try reinstalling it. Some cameras will allow you to install the same version over the current one, some won't. It might well be that the currently loaded firmware in your camera has been corrupted.