# Why won't my Nikon D3100 go into Manual mode when I set it?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, manual-mode

I have a problem with my Nikon D3100. When I set it to Manual mode, it's actually in Automatic mode. No matter what I try it's always Automatic mode. At the same time, not all other modes are working. I don't know what is wrong.

Is the camera broken, and if so is there a solution for that?

I tried a software update, and resetting the camera, but nothing is working.

Comment: [Related](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/72484/47295), [also](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40882/47295).

Comment: This seems like a hardware failure. How old is the camera and do you have any warranty left?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the camera broken, and if so is there a solution for that?

Yes, it sounds like the camera is broken. I cannot think of a Nikon setting that would override your selection of Manual or the other modes in the way you describe.

The solution will be to contact Nikon in your country of purchase.

There are possibly 1 or 2 things you might try though - if you have access to another battery, try that, in case it's actually your battery failing to deliver the power that is needed. I would also try removing the lens, ensuring all contacts are clean, and replacing the lens - again, you never know what might be affecting the camera's settings and software, and there is not much else you can try anyway.